# PHP Responding back to Facebook Webhook API

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, http-headers, webhooks

Facebook made a recent change to Leadgen Webhooks where you've to respond with "200 OK" for each lead that comes in or they'll keep pinging you with that lead. Problem is, they don't mention if there's a way to do that and I've been trying to send a response but unsuccessfully so far.

What I've tried so far:

`status_header(200);`

`http_response_code(200);`

`header[$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 200 OK']`

`header[$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 200 OK', true, 200);`

```
function handle_200() {
    status_header(200);
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 200 OK');
    error_log('test'); // This never even runs
}
add_action('send_headers', 'handle_200', 1);
```

None of the above has worked. I've also checked to ensure that at the point I was trying to change the status header, the current headers have not been sent by checking with `headers_sent()` and that returned a `FALSE`.

I've also tried checking if the status header can be seen through either one of these:

```
error_log(print_r(getallheaders(), true));
error_log(print_r(headers_list(), true));
```

But neither printed out the status header, but if I were to do something like `header('foo: bar')`, that would be seen in the headers list.

I'm at a complete loss, any help to point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

That being said, it might be relevant to mention that this script is running in the theme functions of a Wordpress Environment. Furthermore, the script itself (where I'm making these changes) is running within `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` (not sure if relevant).

**EDIT:** I just found out that when I cause a Fatal Error that causes my script to end prematurely, Facebook receives a 200 OK response (ironically). This makes me think that the problem is because of running the script within `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean()`. Could that be delaying the header response?

**EDIT 2:** This remains unresolved. I've a temporary solution which successfully sends a response 35% of the time. I'm at a point where I get a lead from the webhook, retrieve the info from the lead and then do a SQL query to check if that lead has been received before, if it has, `exit(200)`. As simple as that, how can that take time *for leads that already exist*? It wouldn't! Yet my server (according to Facebook's Ad tool) still times out (without a response) 50% of the time? Something doesn't add up.

Comment: PHP sends `200 OK` by default already. You shouldn't need to add *any* code.

Comment: I think the problem is with running the script within ob_start() and ob_get_contents(). That probably delays the PHP response?

Comment: Not unless you're doing something that takes a long time *within* that output buffering. Your script has to finish running in something like 15-20 seconds. If you're doing extensive processing that takes a long time, you should put it into a queue or something so you can respond within the timeout.

Comment: If you take a look at my edit, something of that sort is indeed happening. I'm not sure how I can put things in a queue, but can I force an early status response somewhere instead?

I've a couple loops going through the lead responses. Which is why I think it makes sense to send a response before the loops

Comment: You should save the webhook info to a database, and have a cron or something process it on the backend. Facebook won't recognize your response as successful until the script completes.

Comment: That cannot be the only way around this... I'll have to re-write months of work. It doesn't make sense to me why Facebook wouldn't take a response earlier than that

Comment: `200 OK` means "all done, you can hang up now". Even if you manage to send an early response by flushing the output buffer early, it's going to result in Facebook saying "bye!" and your script ending anyways. Moving your processing into a queue is a relatively simple process in most cases, and should generally not include a complete rewrite.

Comment: If you look at my newest answer. I did exactly that, I've tested this and it didn't end my script prematurely either. I did this right at the start, and my script still successfully continues to send out emails and save to the Databases as it should. I assumed it should be fine since `ob_flush()` does not end the buffer output. Is there any potential issue with this approach?

Comment: Yes, there's the potential for Facebook hanging up and your PHP script terminating as a result. Or of Facebook hanging up after 15-20 seconds due to their timeouts. Or there could be an transient error in your processing, but Facebook won't re-deliver the webhook because you said it succeeded. Your approach is not ideal, and you should strongly consider queuing up stuff like sending emails.

Comment: Do you have any example of putting things in a queue in PHP while allowing the buffer to be outputted? I'm not sure I fully understand the logic behind it and how to apply it

Comment: You'd just save the JSON you received to a database, and have a cron script that'd regularly fetch items to be processed from that database. Same code would apply, the JSON would just be coming from your DB instead of the webhook call.

Comment: So how'd the cron job know when to run? Or would it just run at like 1 min intervals? And how would you keep the database current? Would you delete the lead from the database after each cron run (that way ensuring only undelivered leads are within the database) ?

Comment: You run it as frequently as required by your business requirements - for some tasks, hourly might be fine. Yes, you'd delete (or better, do something like set a `processed` flag) in the database.

Comment: I'm not sure if cron jobs is the ideal way of doing this. Sometimes it could be an hour before we receive a lead, and sometimes the minute right after we get one comes the next. The most important thing is that things stay in real-time. Once someone submits their info on Facebook, they should get a an email within 1 minute at the most.... Is there no other queuing method that would achieve the same desired output? The simpler the better.

Comment: Again, the frequency is **up to you**. If you need it to be a minute, have it run every minute.